# Why I am not able to deploy my Jar file via eclipse plugin for Teradata

Tags: java, teradata

I installed the eclipse plugin for Teradata and try to follow the following [tutorial](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/articles/creating-a-simple-java-user-defined-function-using-the-teradata-plug-in-for-eclipse).

When I try to deploy my jar file I see the error User does not have EXECUTE PROCEDURE access to SQLJ.REPLACE_Jar.

I also grant access to user over the database by using the following queries.

```
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE ON Project TO user1;
GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE ON Project TO user1;
GRANT CREATE EXTERNAL PROCEDURE ON Project TO user1;
     
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON Project TO user1;
```

These queries run successfully but still, I am not able to deploy my jar file. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks a lot.
[image]

Picture of Doc

[image]

Comment: So did you `GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE ON SQLJ.REPLACE_Jar TO user1;` as the message suggests?

Comment: Yes, I did and the query is successful.

Comment: When I try to register the jar file via Teradata studio I see this error.     [  reate/Replace Java XSP/UDF passed an unacceptable signature. Correct the signature.   ]

Comment: That means there is some issue with the "signature" in the EXTERNAL NAME clause. Were you able to successfully "deploy" the jar?

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is signature. . I am doing exactly as in the documentation mentioned.

Comment: The "signature" gives the name needed to invoke the method, argument types, return type.
 The EXTERNAL NAME clause needs to match what was defined in Java. For a scalar function,
jarid:packagename.classname.methodname(_argumenttypes_) returns _returntype_ Note that the first part is the jarid you used in the "deploy" step  and class / method names are case-sensitive (and by Java convention package names should be lowercase).

Comment: Fred: I check the codes and even I tried with the exact copy and paste what they show in the documentation. Still, I get the same error. I updated my question and added a picture of the documentation.

Comment: Documentation is a different function - maybe start a new question showing exactly what you are doing and what that error is? Also note that the documentation screenshot shows a 2-level name for the method while the plugin puts the class within a package so needs a 3-level reference in the EXTERNAL NAME clause

Answer (score 0):

My question has 2 parts one error appears when I use the plugin ( As shown in the picture) and one error when I run the query on Teradata studio. I am following Fred advice to find the issue but I did manage to run the plugin successfully and created a function.

The solution of error is this

```
 GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE  ON  SQLJ.ALTER_JAVA_PATH TO dbc;
 GRANT EXECUTE PROCEDURE  ON  SQLJ.REPLACE_JAR TO dbc;
```

This will allow the user to run the function successfully.

2nd part still working on.